# SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyS0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyS0'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, iot

I am try to execute python code for `gsm module` in `raspberry pi`.

I got an error at next code:

```
port=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0",baudrate=9600,timeout=1)
```

Error info:

> SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyS0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyS0'

How to solve these plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

> SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyS0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyS0'

This only means you do not have permission to operate hardware, so you need to use `sudo` to execute your script.

Detail see this [article](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/root.md)